# Is omp_set_num_threads routine used to set hardware threads or software threads?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, openmpi

I've recently started to study parallel computing along with implementation examples but I'm not able to figure out whether **omp_set_num_threads routine** sets the limit for hardware threads or software threads for a program.

Comment: IIUC, the hardware number of threads is determined when the CPU is fabricated, so I would say it is software.

Answer (score 2):

Mark's comment is correct in that the number of cores available is configured at fabrication time.  It can be further restricted by BIOS settings, by the hyper-visor, the OS or other software layers that are used to launch your program.

Out of what is then "visible" to your program, `omp_set_num_threads()` sets the number of OpenMP threads for the execution of the next parallel region.  So, it's the number of software threads.  Note, you can a smaller number than available cores, which means that you're *under subscribing* the system, that is, you leave cores idle. You can also pass a larger number to `omp_set_num_threads()` and *over subscribing* the system, that is, multiple software threads are running on the same core.

Usually, unless you want to explicitly under or over subscribe, there's no need to use `omp_set_num_threads()`, as typically OpenMP will detect the available cores for the program and use that as the default.